# How to sort language select list on current language context

Tags: 8, forms, i18n-l10n

I have a form with a language field with the language select list widget.
The options of this field contains an array with a pattern like

```
['langcode' => t('language')]
```

Now I want to sort these options in the right order.

The default sorting is on the value but not on the translated one.

e.g. ['de' => t('german')] which I translated into "Deutsch" will now sort under "g" instead of "d".

So I did try to do it in a form alter hook and a preprocess hook but this is not the right place to do it, because the values are still untranslated here.

So my question is how can I sort these options if the values are translated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I did this in a form_alter_hook.

This worked for me.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function arph_profile_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $language_options = $form["field_languages"]["widget"][0]["value"]["#options"];
  $new_language_options = [];
  foreach($language_options as $langcode => $language) {
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup $language */
    $new_language_options[$langcode] = $language->render();
  }
  asort($new_language_options); // We need to keep the keys here.
  $form["field_languages"]["widget"][0]["value"]["#options"] = $new_language_options;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i think it can be done in a hook_form_alter()

if the options are in $form['languages'], you can do something like :

```
$language_options = $form['languages'];
```

then manipulate the array $language_options, until it has the order you need
then override it in form :

```
$form['languages'] = $language_options;
```

Comment: The problem is that the values are untranslated in a form_alter_hook.
I could sort it by key but this also doesnt work because the langcode differs from the value.

Comment: I need to render the translatablemarkup first than build a new array and sort its values.